# how to get the version of Selenium RC server

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am using selenium2 RC with the python client (selenium.py) and I need to get the version of the selenium on the server. (for example "2rc2","2rc3" etc.)

is there any command i can send to the server to get its version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get this information from the Selenium object using get_eval.

E.g.

```
>> from selenium import selenium
>> browser = selenium('localhost','4444','*firefox','http://google.com')
>> version = browser.get_eval('Selenium.version + Selenium.revision')
>> print version
u'2.0rc3'
```

Comment: This needed a `browser.start()` call for me before I could call `get_eval`

Comment: I am getting 'error: [Errno 61] Connection refused' error. What could that be?

Answer (score 5):

I know this was already answered but it may help someone else. Another way to get your selenium server's version is right click the selenium-server.jar, and open it was any file archiver software such as 7zip or winrar. There you should find a file called VERSION.txt which will tell you your servers version

Comment: the question was how to know the version of the selenium server I communicate with, I have no access to its jar file.

Comment: `pip freeze` will show you if you installed selenium with pip.